# 2 layers embedded where clause with mongodb and python eve

Tags: python, mongodb, eve

I have a brand, a model and a vehicle sources. I just want to get all vehicle by given brand Id.. 
I'

Vehicle schema has this in db source

```
'model': {
    'type': 'objectid',
    'data_relation': {
        'resource': 'vehicle_model',
        'field': '_id',
        'embeddable': True
    },
    'required': True
},
```

And vehicle_model has this source:

```
'brand': {
    'type': 'objectid',
    'data_relation': {
        'resource': 'vehicle_brand',
        'field': '_id',
        'embeddable': True
    },
    'required': True
},
```

So, when I try to get all vehicle by given brand id it returns empty.

```
http://localhost/vehicle?where=model.brand==5ab63e9c63da12227a2d3e43
```

Is there a way to filter for two layer embedded resources?